# when using beamer, inline math mode in tikzpicture does not show $x$ like when not using beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, xepersian

When I put a formula inside a node in tikzpicture while using beamer, it doesn't show it as it does when I don't use beamer. Consider the code here:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation}
        x^2
    \end{equation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at(0,0) (Example:) {
            \begin{minipage}{2cm}
                $x^2$
            \end{minipage}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

here is the output: [image]

I have tried compiling it with both XeLatex and PdfLatex, still no luck!

How can I get a more beautiful $x^2$ when using beamer and tikzpicture simultaneously?

This $x^2$ is what I get when I don't use beamer document and use article mode:

[image]

Edit: As for the answer of [@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1683134?noredirect=1), I aim to use Persian fonts and Xepersian in beamer because the language of my presentation is Persian and hence using Serif font is of no good here. This is what I want to have in my presentation:

[image]
This is the code for the image above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\setdigitfont{Yas}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        x^2
    \end{equation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at(0,0) (Example:) {
            \begin{minipage}{2cm}
                $x^2$
            \end{minipage}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What exactly do you mean by "more beautiful"? The alignment, the font, the spacing, ...

Comment: You're question isn't really clear, but are you maybe looking for `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`?

Comment: @Οὖτις The font I guess, since it is not the same when I'm not using beamer but entering a the same formula inside a node. Maybe I'll need to edit the question to clarify "more beautiful" more regorously.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have edited the question, is it clear enough now?

Comment: If the problem depends on the use of a Persian font, then the code of the MWE in the question should show that too, so in particular use a (free) Persian font.

Comment: @cabohah I've tried with a Persian font (Yas) but the problem exists in beamer mode but not in article mode.

Comment: I've not said, you the code should use `article`. I've said, the code should show the problem. So if it depends on `beamer` and a Persian font, the code should use `beamer` and a Persian font.  The MWE is not just for fun. We just should be able to reproduce the issue without any changes to the code. Otherwise the code is not a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beamer uses a sans serif font by default. If you would like to use serif font for math, you can use `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation}
        x^2
    \end{equation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at(0,0) (Example:) {
            \begin{minipage}{2cm}
                $x^2$
            \end{minipage}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you'd like to use custom fonts, use the `professionalfonts` theme:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\setdigitfont{Yas}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation}
        x^2
    \end{equation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at(0,0) (Example:) {
            \begin{minipage}{2cm}
                $x^2$
            \end{minipage}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it. However, I don't aim to use serif font, since the language of my presentation is Persian and I want to use persian fonts and Xepersian package. what do you suggest I should do? Limit my expectations...? :))

Comment: @AmirrezaTaghizadeh Then please edit your question to include a minimal working example of your actual problem. If you want math to look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUGrF.png then you want to use serif math, because that's what you show in  your image.

Comment: I edited my question. I would appreciate it if you could consider reopening it. I think it is a problem when you are writing in Persian and using beamer since I've seen a persian presentation with this issue.

Comment: @AmirrezaTaghizadeh Your question does not show any code with Persian fonts

Comment: Let me edit that once more.

Comment: I added the latex code of the last image of my question.

Comment: @AmirrezaTaghizadeh See my edited answer

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked like a charm!

Comment: @AmirrezaTaghizadeh You're welcome!